# NestJs Socket io adapter: Server does not add CORS headers to handshake's response if allowFunction is called with false. Bug or misconfiguration?

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-gateways

authenticated-socket-io.adapter.ts

```
export class AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter extends IoAdapter {
  private readonly authService: AuthService;

  constructor(private app: INestApplicationContext) {
    super(app);
    this.authService = this.app.get(AuthService);
  }

  createIOServer(port: number, options?: SocketIO.ServerOptions): any {
    options.allowRequest = async (request, allowFunction) => {
      const { authorized, errorMessage } = await this.check(parse(request?.headers?.cookie || '').jwt, [UserRole.ADMIN]);
      if (!authorized) {
        return allowFunction(errorMessage, false);
      }

      return allowFunction(null, true);
    };


    return super.createIOServer(port, options);
  }
```

main.ts

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:4200'],
    credentials: true
  });
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new AuthenticatedSocketIoAdapter(app));
```

When authorization is successful:
[authorization is successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yunq.png)

When authorization fails:
[authorization fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwjHr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:
the function from socket io handling the error message:

```
/**
 * Sends an Engine.IO Error Message
 *
 * @param {http.ServerResponse} response
 * @param {code} error code
 * @api private
 */

function sendErrorMessage (req, res, code) {
  var headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };

  var isForbidden = !Server.errorMessages.hasOwnProperty(code);
  if (isForbidden) {
    res.writeHead(403, headers);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      code: Server.errors.FORBIDDEN,
      message: code || Server.errorMessages[Server.errors.FORBIDDEN]
    }));
    return;
  }
  if (req.headers.origin) {
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = req.headers.origin;
  } else {
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
  }
  if (res !== undefined) {
    res.writeHead(400, headers);
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      code: code,
      message: Server.errorMessages[code]
    }));
  }
}
```

here the "code" param will be the one I pass in here "allowFunction(**errorMessage**, false)"
That value has to be one of "0", "1", "2", "3" or "4", otherwise the isForbidden will be false, thus not setting the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header.

```
Server.errorMessages = {
  0: 'Transport unknown',
  1: 'Session ID unknown',
  2: 'Bad handshake method',
  3: 'Bad request',
  4: 'Forbidden'
};
```

Hope this helps someone one day.